# console.log is not working in iOS Phonegap App even after adding the console plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created a Phonegap iOS App in Cordova CLI . I have added the console plugin and yes deviceready is called successfully but console.log is not working and does not print any thing in XCode log.

**Plugin Installation :-**

> **cordova -v**
>   3.3.1-0.3.1
>
> **sudo cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.console**
>   Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via plugin registry
>   Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.console" for ios
>   Preparing ios project
>   org.apache.cordova.console installed on ios.
>
> **sudo cordova plugins ls**
>   [ 'org.apache.cordova.console',
>     'org.apache.cordova.device',
>     'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
>     'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',
>     'org.apache.cordova.globalization',
>     'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser',
>     'org.apache.cordova.media',
>     'org.apache.cordova.network-information',
>     'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen',
>     'org.apache.cordova.vibration' ]

**Java Script :-**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
       this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
       document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
       app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
       console.log('Device Ready Received'); //It is not working
       alert("Device ready called");  //It is Working
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the plugin and reinstall it?

Comment: yes. the same problem i got after reinstall. :(

Comment: Hm...
It is working for me.

Maybe you try it again with a little new sample project. There also is a newer version of Cordova (3.3.1-0.4.2) available. Maybe this one works for you.

Comment: Check also the Console is defined in the config.xml : `<feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
</feature>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by doing these steps

**Step 1 :**

I Just copy a directory from another cordova project where console.log was working

```
sudo cp -r DIFF_CORDOVA_PROJECT_PATH/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.console CURRENT_CORDOVA_PROJECT_PATH/platforms/ios/www/plugins/
```

**Step 2 :**

Add the Code in CURRENT_CORDOVA_PROJECT_PATH/platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js file under module.exports JSON array

```
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.console/www/console-via-logger.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.console.console",
    "clobbers": [
        "console"
    ]
},
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.console/www/logger.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.console.logger",
    "clobbers": [
        "cordova.logger"
    ]
}
```

**Step 3 :**

Adding Meta data on the same cordova_plugins.js file in module.exports.metadata JSON Array :-

"org.apache.cordova.console": "0.2.7"

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was probably because the plugin was installed from a Windows machine the first time and it work previously only for the Android platform.
when I try to reinstall it from my Macintosh I encountered the same problem of Shashi.

This has been caused from the missing of the source file CDVLogger.m  in the compile source list. So I recommend to check if this file is already added by:

Click on root Project file in the Xcode explorer > Build Phases > Compile Sources section

If the CDVLogger.m file is not present add it and try to Run the project again. This fixed the issue for me.

EDIT: In addition be sure that your index.html page contains this HTML:

```
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
    <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
    <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of solutions posted here in stackoverflow but nothing was working for me. After putting the cordova.js outside of my personal JS folder console.log was working fine.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` inside the  section of the code

Answer (score 0):

I've had this as well. I would get no console output and my app's default.html file would never really load. The issue in my situation was that my console plugin was literally one decimal off/old (0.2.12 instead of 0.2.13). Soon as I updated everything started working again... argh!

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035260/826308

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do following action:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
if (window.cordova.logger) {
    window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();
} } document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);`
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case, following div was missing

```
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
  <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
  <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
</div>
```