# console.log not working in phonegap when built for ios (plugin is installed)

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm pulling my hair out on this one. I'm using phonegap 3.4 to build an iOS app. When I build the project and run in the simulator, I want to view the output of console.log in the xcode debug window, but it's not working. I've installed the org.apache.cordova.console plugin, but no luck. I see some normal debug output like "Resetting plugins due to page load" but none of my console.logs appear. Any ideas?

And this did not solve my issue: [console.log is not working in iOS Phonegap App even after adding the console plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826277/console-log-is-not-working-in-ios-phonegap-app-even-after-adding-the-console-plu?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried the developer console in safari?

Comment: It shows up there, but I need to be able to see the console when I'm running on a device, not just the simulator.

Comment: If you plugin in an iOS device to your computer you can run the same inspector.

Comment: That works. Had to enable it in the device settings. Is there no way to make the log messages appear in xcode?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you would have to write a plugin for it.

Comment: The error `Resetting plugins due to page load` could be caused by a multitude of reasons, can we see your codes? If you've correctly installed the plugin, the `console.log()` messages should appear in the Xcode log messages.

Answer (score 2):

try **alert();**
it is basically the same as **console.log();**
but you need to install different plugins: **org.apache.cordova.dialogs**

i dont have iphone nor mac so i can't guarantee it will work on them. But in one android device that i tried, when the **console.log()** fails. **Alert()** succeeds.

There are 2 types of alert:

> 1. **alert('text');** //this is actually javascript
> 2. **navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])** //this is phonegap function

In my case. i have only need to use the first one. 
further documentation on the second alert function is below:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

i hope it will work on xcode too.

Comment: this was a sufficient workaround for my needs, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the console plugin. While Android is able to do this out of the box, logging to console is otherwise not supported on iOS:

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: call `logger.__onDeviceReady` function from your deviceready listener function:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (window.cordova.logger) {
        window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: i dont see `window.cordova.logger` on os x 10.13.6, cordova 8.0.0, cordova-ios 4.4.5

Answer (score -4):

Try to use "document.write" instead.