# How to update the already added Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm the development of cordova plugin in android.

Updating the javascript of Cordova plugin are not updated.

1. change:"./test/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js"
2. cordova build android

   - Expect the update:/test/platforms/android/assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js

In the version up of cordova it seems behavior has changed.

- 5.3.3-: OK
- 5.4.1+: NG

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update cordova plugins in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783968/update-cordova-plugins-in-one-command)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of updating the plugin, I've found that I can remove it and re-add it. In my case, I'm referencing the plugin source code locally, via the --link option:

```
cordova plugin rm plugin-name
cordova plugin add custom-plugins/plugin-name --link
```

To make sure the correct version number is reflected in the newly added plugin, you can use:

```
cordova plugin ls
```

Answer (score -2):

Run The below command

```
cordova plugin update plugin-name
```

Comment: Don't see the `update` parameter as an available option.  According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28802478), the way to do it without any custom helpers is to first remove and then re-add

Comment: Output: Cordova does not know update; try `cordova help` for a list of all the available commands.