# how to reinstall plugins already recoded in config.xml in cordova?

Tags: cordova

Let's say I've install some plugins in cordova, and it has been **recoded in `config.xml`:**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.6.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1" />
```

**Now, if I delete the plugins folder, how can I reinstall all the plugins easily?**

**I don't have to type all the `cordova add plugin` order, do I?**

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

And so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783968/update-cordova-plugins-in-one-command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just run `cordova prepare`

It should recreate all the plugins and platforms from the `config.xml`

But if you deleted the plugins folder, they are also in the platforms folder and plugins will fail to install, so delete platforms folder too.