# UIWebView error submiting ionic app to Apple

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, uiwebview

I have developed an ionic app that is for Android and iOS.
When I try to submit the application to iOS I always receive the same error.

[image: Error report from Apple]

I searched in my entire project and I can't find any  reference to UIWebView.

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783968/update-cordova-plugins-in-one-command) to update all my plugins.

I added this code to my config.xml:

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

I updated my cordova and my ionic versions:
cordova version - 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
ionic version - 6.10.1

I've tried several tutorials like the ones on these links and others:

https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2020/01/27/Removal-of-UIWebview/

But whenever I submit the application to Apple, it gets rejected because of this error.

What can I do to remove UIWebView or get my application approved?

Thanks

Update:

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
@angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 1.5.2
@capacitor/core : 1.0.0-beta.19

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 16 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

ios-sim : 8.0.2
NodeJS  : v12.18.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm     : 6.14.5
OS      : macOS Catalina
Xcode   : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c

Updateing my question using @Harish answer

[image: cordova-plugin-webview version]

[image: WKWebViewOnly]

[image: cordova-ios version]

However I still get the same error

[image: Apple error report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my app for the exact issue recently and Here are the steps I have followed to fix the issue:

1. Ensure your `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` is updated to the latest version `5.0.0`. You need to run these two commands to do that.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

2. Ensure your `cordova-ios` is updated to the latest version `6.0.0`. Run this command to update it.

```
npm install cordova-ios@latest --save
```

3. Check your `package.json` to see if the versions are updated for both `cordova-ios` and `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`.
4. Ensure you add `WKWebViewOnly` preference to `config.xml` file.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    ...
</platform>
```

5. This is the most important step. Ensure you remove the `ios` platform and add it again. Run these commands to remove and add the ios platform.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Now, when you build the ios app and publish it to the app store, you can see the issue will be fixed.

Comment: hi, I have added some images to my question

Comment: Can you check if the same versions are present inside the ios folder? Just try to do the 5th step. It should work.

Comment: After executing the 5 step the cordova-ios gets downgraded automarically to 5.1.1

Comment: After some time I managed it to work. My problem was in the firebase module. I remove it and executed your steps and I worked

Comment: Which module was that? Can you add the name of the module here?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, but if I included the firbase module I would get this error from Apple. So I removed this module and it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. You might be using old ionic version.
   The version you have pasted in your question is version of Ionic CLI.
   run "ionic info" in  you project folder to see what Ionic framework version you are using.
2. if you are using ionic framework 3+ version.
   then install ionic webview plugin by:

   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save

Comment: Hy, I have updated my question withe the info of the "ionic info"