# Ionic: iOS UIWebView are no longer accepted

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Facing issue in Ionic: iOS App Store connect(UIWebView are no longer accepted)

Followed these steps but nothing working- same error.
https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/
Please advise.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIWebView error submiting ionic app to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593905/uiwebview-error-submiting-ionic-app-to-apple)

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded to WKWebView successfully then take a look at some 3rd-party plugins in your app. They might be using UIWebView. Your application will be rejected if any instance of UIWebView is detected.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/#upgrading-to-wkwebview-uiwebview-users-only