# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "BeepingmeServiceProvider" 1.7 (1). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Comment: what cordova version are you using??? Please Upgrade to latest cordova version.

Comment: Check out this https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIWebView error submiting ionic app to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593905/uiwebview-error-submiting-ionic-app-to-apple)